# How to send pdf file as an attachment in Django

Tags: django, django-email

I have a form where the user can ask for an document. They need to enter the name and the email address and the document will be sent to that email address.

How to do that?

My code is as follows:

```
if download_form.is_valid():
        ln_go = get_lang_code(request, request.GET.get('lang'))
        file_to_be_sent = "/assets/documents/case_study" + ln_go + ".pdf"
        name = request.POST.get('name')
        email = request.POST.get('email')

        msg = EmailMultiAlternatives('Het aangevraagde document',
                                     'Geachte {0}, <br/><br />In bijlage sturen wij u het aangevraagde document door. <br /><br />Met vriendelijke groeten, <br /><br /> Het Autralis team'.format(name),
                                     'no-reply@autralis.com',
                                     [email, ], # TO
                                     ['some-email-address@gmail.com', ]) # cc
        msg.content_subtype = "html"  # Main content is now text/html
        msg.attach("case_study.pdf", file_to_be_sent, "application/pdf")
        msg.send()
```

And the project tree where those documents are is as follows:

[image]

I have two problems:

1. **First problem**: email = request.POST.get('email') is `myemail@hotmail.com,` but the email has not been send to that email, the cc email address `some-email-address@gmail.com` get the mail but the attachment is not correct
2. **Second problem** is the attachment. My attachment is 1.2MB but I do not get what it should be. I get something as follows:

[image]

Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Perhaps hotmail is rejecting your email as spam but gmail isn't. The second argument to [`attach`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/email/#emailmessage-objects) should be the content of the file. You are passing the filename instead. You might be able to use `attach_file` instead.

Comment: As an aside, it's better to use the form's `cleaned_data` instead of `request.POST`, e.g. `email = form.cleaned_data['email']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should put `content` in the attach method:

```
import os
from django.conf import settings

file_to_be_sent = "assets/documents/case_study{}.pdf".format(ln_go)
file_to_be_sent = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, file_to_be_sent)
with open(file_to_be_sent) as f:
    msg.attach("case_study.pdf", f.read(), "application/pdf")
```

or use the `attach_file` method

```
msg.attach_file(file_to_be_sent)
```

details for the methods in the [EmailMessage](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/email/#django.core.mail.EmailMessage)

Comment: I get an error: `IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/assets/documents/case_study_en.pdf'`

Comment: because you use linux absolute path.

Comment: do you have `Base_Dir` in the settings or something else to generate correct full path for your file?

Comment: No. I do not have settings at all.

Comment: you have the file `YourProejct/settings.py`

Comment: sorry i can't help you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172243/discussion-between-boky-and-bear-brown).